# Fix broken GET variable

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, get

I am using a GET variable to select a specific item to display on the page. My URL would usually look like:

```
/?type=xxxx
```

I then have a login plugin (Wordpress) which adds `?redirect=ok` to the URL on submission. Unfortunately, this then makes the URL look like: `/?type=xxxx?redirect=ok` which breaks the previous variable.

I am trying to edit that URL somehow. I thought about a few methods:

- .htaccess to find and rewrite the `?redirect=ok` to blank or to &redirect=ok
- PHP to strip that part out of the string and then redirect

None of these seemed to work.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Well, why don't you just edit the plugin and count the get parameters? If there are already some the plugin adds &redirect=ok otherwise the plugin adds ?redirect=ok

Comment: Either edit the plugin to use `add_query_arg()` which will handle parsing the URL for you. Or, edit the link you're creating to use `add_query_arg()`. More here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Comment: I did think about that but I didn't write the plugin so I don't know exactly where that code is. I've asked the developer for help though.

Comment: To track it down, try a find in an IDE or `grep -Rn "?redirect=ok" /path/to/my/site"` to give you possible locations of where the code is. This will help us help you (if you supply code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `mod_rewrite` fix for this strange problem.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*\?type=.*?)\?(redirect=ok) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1&%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: All of the answers were valid and appreciated but this one was the quickest and easiest for a novice like me. Thanks!